# I cannot annex Indian state, only "force migration"

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

**Question:**

I made my first colony in Brasil and I occupied land of some "Tapuia" Indians neighboring to my colony. But in peace negotiations I see only "**Force migration**". I cannot annex them or claim the province. What is the problem? Perhaps I have wrong casus belli. It seems I'm unable to get "conquest" casus belli against Indians?

- Do I need research some tech/idea for that?
- Maybe I need create some "core" in Americas first? How can I do that? Do I need to grow the colony to "City" first?

**background** (not necessary to read):

I play play Bohemia at year 1530 - it took me long time to get to the sea. I started to think about colonization only after I became HRE Emperor and annexed Burgundy (including Holland). I terribly lag behind Portugal, Castil, England and even France in colonization. But my army is strongest in Europe (4000 man stronger than France and Ottomans).

In general I find it very hard to grow colonies (it is extremely slow, all other nations grow colonies much faster). I was thinking that by conquest of Indian lands can compensate my lack of exploration/expansion ideas, using strength of my army.

I have researched only "exploration" idea to "Quest for New world" stage. I don't have "expansion idea" yet. I have barely colonial reach to touch America (just Antilles + apex of Brasil).

Before I finished "Offensive" ideas, and picked "Influence" (which I regret, since I would prefer colonization over influence, but that was before I claimed Holland).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the "Force Migration" Casus Belli, you cannot take any territory, as discussed [on this reddit link.](https://www.reddit.com/r/eu4/comments/4f5r4s/how_to_end_a_war_with_casus_belli_force_migration/)

To take territory from natives, you need to fabricate claims and declare war with a conquest casus belli (requires a core or completed exploration ideas), or manufacture any other CB that lets you take territory (or you can declare with no CB, but that has strong consequences).

You can get a territorial core when your colony becomes a full city. If you have I believe the El Dorado DLC, then your Brazilian colonies will form a colonial nation when you have 5 cities in the region, at which point they'll start expanding on their own through colonization and conquest (though they'll be pretty slow until they're big enough to have a strong income).

A list of casus belli can be found [here](https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/Casus_belli).

Comment: As a further note, the issue with a conquest CB is that migratory nations can simply move out of whatever province(s) you have claims on, preemptively ending the war. This has happened to me.

Comment: aha ... so I cannot conquare any land before I reach city in neihboring colony (since I don't have a core)? That is pretty sad :( ... I don't get how England was able to build those cities so fast, that now thay seal-club all the indians. By colony takes for ever (30 colonist per year => 33 years to make one city) ... do you recall colonist before reaching city (in order to make second colony?)

Comment: I usually do after about 500 population, yes. You don't want too many settlements at a time though unless you have a large income, because their costs scale exponentially. You can increase your colonists per year though (see https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/Colonization#Global_settler_increase)

Comment: If I recall correctly you can't "no cb" when you have a cb. So, If you have the "Force Migration" cb you can't start a "no cb"-war.